# Create closure using the base R function constructor

Tags: r, function, constructor, closures

Using base R, is it possible to construct a closure from its 3 components directly? All I could manage so far was the slightly verbose

```r
val <- 3L

fun_a <- function(x = 1L) val + x
fun_b <- function(x = 2L) val * x
fun_c <- function(){}

formals(fun_c) <- formals(fun_a)
body(fun_c) <- body(fun_b)
environment(fun_c) <- list2env(list(val = 5L))

fun_c()
#> [1] 5
```

Additionally, I cannot seem to figure out how to call `function()`. Some of the things I have tried:

```r
`function`(formals(fun_a), body(fun_b))
#> Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
`function`(as.pairlist(formals(fun_a)), body(fun_b))
#> Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
do.call(`function`, c(formals(fun_a), body(fun_b)))
#> Error in do.call("function", c(formals(fun_a), body(fun_b))) :
#>  invalid formal argument list for "function"
```

I'm aware of `rlang::new_function()` but here I'm looking for base R solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in R code.  The function implementing `function` is meant to be called from the parser, where

```
function(x = 3) { x }
```

is translated into something like

```
`function`( pairlist(as.name(x) = 3), quote({ x }))
```

but the line above is not legal in R:  there's no way to say that the tag on an element of a list should be a name instead of a character value.  You could write your function in C, or stick with your verbose solution of creating a template and replacing parts of it one at a time.